# Which versions of Ubuntu share /etc/sysctl.conf compatibility?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, sysctl

I am looking to secure my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server and have found a nice script but it was designed for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which includes changes to /etc/sysctl.conf.
Which versions of Ubuntu (or linux in general) share /etc/sysctl.conf compatibility? Can I use the script's /etc/sysctl.conf for Ubuntu 20.04 on my Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Ask the script maintainer. You did not provide enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Proper way to do such things is to add *override files* into `/etc/sysctl.conf.d/`. So in general, I'd advise you to **never** use scripts which change `/etc/sysctl.conf`, because this is the bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, spend effort upgrading the distro, and getting  applications to work on  20.04. As an added bonus, this gains you 2 more years of life.

Read [sysctl documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/fs.html) to get an idea about what each tunable the script tweaks does.

There is no guarantee that kernel settings are relevant or do the same thing to a previous version. In general, most are. sysctl, as a user interface to kernel settings, is relatively stable.

As a practical matter, write your settings to a drop in file, such as `/etc/sysctl.d/tune.conf`  Very easy to install, compared to inserting lines in an existing file.